# Edge Router X SFP - Portforwarding Public IP

Tags: router, port-forwarding

I have a edge router X and we are hosting a few Minecraft servers for friends. We have a few servers in a rack and around 8 usable IPs. We have assigned 1 of the IPs to our Minecraft box running CentOS making an eth alias. Then in the Minecraft config you enter your IP and it binds the server to the given public IP rather than a internal one. As we have other servers on the network we use NAT for routing.

Is there a way to route IP to itself using NAT, or some way to allow a port without port forwarding? The route is direct and doesn't need to go to a internal address.